# What is the difference between method overloading and overriding?

Tags: java, overloading, overriding

What is the difference between **overloading** a method and **overriding** a method? Can anyone explain it with an example?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Method **overloading** deals with the notion of having two or more methods in the same class with the same name but different arguments.

```
void foo(int a)
void foo(int a, float b)
```

Method **overriding** means having two methods with the same arguments, but different implementations. One of them would exist in the parent class, while another will be in the derived, or child class. The `@Override` annotation, while not required, can be helpful to [enforce proper overriding of a method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/94411/1079354) at compile time.

```
class Parent {
    void foo(double d) {
        // do something
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {

    @Override
    void foo(double d){
        // this method is overridden.  
    }
}
```

Comment: `@Override` is not required. It's a good practice, but not required.

Comment: Sorry @GriffeyDog. You are right "@Override" is not compulsory.But to remember that you are overriding a method, it is a good practice..Thanks for reminding..

Comment: Overloading need not be in the same class but can be also be done between parent class and derived class.

Comment: Re @happs's comment: It's still overloading if a parent class defines one signature, and a derived class defines a second signature, per [JLS§8.4.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.9): *"If two methods of a class (whether both declared in the same class, or both inherited by a class, or one declared and one inherited) have the same name but signatures that are not override-equivalent, then the method name is said to be overloaded."*

Answer (score 35):

**Method overriding** is when a child class redefines the same method as a parent class, with the same parameters. *For example*, the standard Java class `java.util.LinkedHashSet` extends `java.util.HashSet`. The method `add()` is overridden in `LinkedHashSet`. If you have a variable that is of type `HashSet`, and you call its `add()` method, it will call the appropriate implementation of `add()`, based on whether it is a `HashSet` or a `LinkedHashSet`. This is called polymorphism.

**Method overloading** is defining several methods in the same class, that accept different numbers and types of parameters. In this case, the actual method called is decided at compile-time, based on the number and types of arguments. *For instance*, the method `System.out.println()` is overloaded, so that you can pass ints as well as Strings, and it will call a different version of the method.

Comment: If you have a child class that defines the same method with different parameters then is that considered to be both overriding and overloading?

Comment: then it's overloading only as it's not overriding any of the parent method.

Comment: To add on that, the next question would be which method to execute? , the summary is :in overloading we follow the reference type in execution, in overriding we follow the object type in execution.