# method overloading in same class with different params name

Tags: java, oop, overloading

I have a method in super class

```
protected int discount(int amount)
```

and a method in subclass

```
protected int discount(int amount1)
```

Is the method in subclass is going to overload or not???

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OP can easily test this in any electric device that has a compiler.

Comment: @AliAnsari You probably mean `override`. Please do read the difference between `override` and `overload`, e.g. in (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374399/difference-between-method-overloading-and-overriding-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, method overloading works if you have different type or number of arguments. variable names don't matter

Comment: could have been a comment..

Comment: Thnx. thats i wanted, percise one.

Answer (score 0):

(Excepting your misuse of terminology.) In Java, if you have a function in a sub-class that is identical in name, parameters and (loosely), the return type to a function in the super-class then objects of the sub-class type will use the function in the sub-class. This is called function **overriding**. (And in Java, unlike C++, is automatic).

(Function **overloading** is used to describe functions that have identical **names** but differing parameters.)