# Is this method overloading, overriding or none?

Tags: java, polymorphism, overloading, overriding

[Difference between method overloading and overriding in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374399/difference-between-method-overloading-and-overriding-in-java) does not give the correct answer. Below is java code.

**Parent** class

```
public class Parent {
    void display() {
        // some code
    }
}
```

**Child** class

```
public class child extends Parent
    void display(int a) {
        // some code
    }
}
```

**Question:** Is this Method overloading, overriding or none?

Comment: None, and you can check it by placing `@Override` at the method to override to let the compiler check for yourself.

Comment: I am confused between override and none.

Comment: No need to be confused, your example does neither overload nor override. But if you want to let the compiler check if a method is overridden, you can place `@Override` and the compiler tells you.

Comment: @Smutje, Sorry I am confused between overload and none, but now its clear. Thanks

Comment: @MarounMaroun, marked duplicate answer gives wrong answer for my question. Can you please update it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's overloading (in `child`), because [JLS 8.4.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.9):

> If two methods of a class (**whether both declared in the same class**, or
>   **both inherited by a class**, **or one declared and one inherited**) have the
>   same name but signatures that are not override-equivalent, then the
>   method name is said to be overloaded.

Comment: Thank you, I was confused for this only. Cheers!!!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, can you please update the answer of the question which is being tagged as duplicate of this question.

Answer (score 3):

This is **Overloading**

> Method Overloading - method in Same Class or different class
>
> Method Overriding - method both in Parent Child class

Here method has different signature in both Parent and Child class

Comment: As I understand it if you create two methods that conflict, with the same signature, then the compiler will throw an error unless you include the `@Override` notation.

Comment: @doveyg yes ur correct. But not in this case

Comment: @doveyg: No, it's the other way around: If you include `@Override` on a method that isn't, in fact, an override, the compiler will give you an error. It does not give you an error if you *don't* use `@Override` when you should (because `@Override` was added a **long** time after the language was originally specified). Now, *within the same class*, you can't have two methods with the same name and signature (whether or not you put `@Override` on one of them).

Comment: No, it's overloading (in `child`), see [JLS §8.4.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.9). Overloads don't have to be in the same class, having one inherited and the other declared still overloads.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder corrected, somehow missed and messed completely

Comment: When you get an answer wrong (which we all do sometimes! :-) ) and meanwhile the correct answer has been posted, it's best to just delete your answer.