# Can toString() method take an argument in Java?

Tags: java

I tested this in eclipse, and it didn't give me any exceptions. However I wasn't able to specify the value x. Can toString() take an argument (I know that my example below isn't the greatest)?

Test.java

```
public class Test {

    public String toString(int x){
        return "Hey "+ x;
    }

}
```

Main.java

```
public class Main {
      public static void main(String[] args){

          System.out.println(new Test());


      }
}
```

Comment: It is useless. only toString() is usefull, because already used by other libraries.  You could name it  anotherToString() also ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Can `toString()` take an argument?

Yes, and in this case you'll have an [*overloaded*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) `toString()` method.

When invoking `System.out.println(t)`, however, the `Object#toString()` will be invoked anyway (and you can verify that by checking the [`PrintStream#println(Object t)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/PrintStream.java#PrintStream.print%28java.lang.Object%29) method's source).

In order to invoke your custom `.toString()` method, you have to do (for example):

```
System.out.println(t.toString(5));
```

Comment: Superb, that makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but in this case you won't be overriding the [`Object::toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) method, just creating your own overloading.

Your method is valid

```
public String toString(int x) {
     return "Hey "+ x;
}
```

[Check this question to clarify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374399/what-is-the-difference-between-method-overloading-and-overriding)

To execute it this won't be valid because you will be calling `Test.toString()` not `Test.toString(int)`:

```
System.out.println(new Test());
```

Create an instance and call your method:

```
Test t = new Test();
System.out.println(t.toString(10);
```

OUTPUT:

```
Hey 10
```