# Invoking method with different argument type

Tags: java, inheritance, parameters, arguments, invoke

I am trying to understand inheritance from the Head First Java book. On page 193 I got everything right, and I am trying to invoke a method with a different parameter ( an overloaded method ), but the main class invokes the one inherited from the superclass. How can I invoke the following method?

```
boolean frighten(byte b) {
    System.out.println("a bite?");
    return true;
}
```

I tried to declare a byte, but it did not help.
Thank you guys, here are the codes:

```
public class MonsterT {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Monster[] ma = new Monster[3];
        ma[0] = new Vampire();
        ma[1] = new Dragon();
        ma[2] = new Monster();
        for (int x=0; x < 3; x++) {
            ma[x].frighten(x);
        }

        byte y = 2;

        ma[0].frighten(y);
    }
}

class Monster {
    boolean frighten(int z) {
        System.out.println("arrrgh");
        return true;
    }
}

class Vampire extends Monster {
    boolean frighten(byte b) {
        System.out.println("a bite?");
        return true;
    }


class Dragon extends Monster {
    boolean frighten(int degree) {
        System.out.println("breath fire");
        return true;
    }
```

And the output is: `arrrgh
breath fire
arrrgh
arrrgh`

Comment: What about `((Vampire)ma[0]).frighten(y);`?

Comment: It worked! Can you explain to me, why? Thanks

Comment: because the object at `ma[0]` is a Vampire, you can cast it down from `monster` to `Vampire`

Comment: The class Vampire doesn't override the method frighten() because it's not using the same type of arguments as the parent class does. Use the @Override annotation and see what happens - the compiler would tell you that.

Comment: @the scientific method: please correct your comment, the object ma[0] is monster, not vampire

Comment: @BlackFlag noway, it is a Vampire Object referenced by Monster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point here is the difference between overloading and overriding - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12374437/3021395) for more.

So your class tree looks as follows:

```
 Monster
|       |
Vamire  Dragon
```

This means that the

```
frighten(int z)
```

method is availble by inheritance to all three classes and could be overloaded (= same types - as it has been in the Dragon class).

While the

```
boolean frighten(byte b)
```

Is an overriding (not the same type of parameter), so that you could call

```
frighten(byte) 
   and 
frighten(int)
```

on your Vampire.

Another aspect that comes into play is [object type casting](http://Object%20Type%20Casting%20in%20Java).

So at the end all your objects are "Monsters in the monster array "ma" - and will be seen as monsters.

This will be changed to vampire by the cast that @The Scientific Method demonstrated in it's answer.

Without the cast the byte would be auto type casted to int.

Comment: That's what i thought too, but i didn't understand why   'byte y = 2; ma[0].frighten(y);' didn't work, despite that i gave it a byte argument.

Comment: That's because "Monster[] ma" so all your objects are in a monster array - and will be seen as monsters. This will be changed to vampire by the cast that @The Scientific Method demonstrated in it's answer. Without the cast the byte would be auto type casted to int.

Comment: Added this explanation to the main answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by casting `ma[0]` to `Vampire`: `((Vampire)(ma[0])).frighten(y);`

#### Why it does not work currently?

You can't do that with current structure of classes and methods because of [Method Invocation Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3), applied when you invoke `frighten()` on `Vampire` object with `byte` argument:

> Method invocation contexts allow the use of one of the following:
>
> - an identity conversion (§5.1.1)
> - a widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2)
> - a widening reference conversion (§5.1.5)
> - a boxing conversion (§5.1.7) optionally followed by widening reference
>     conversion
> - an unboxing conversion (§5.1.8) optionally followed by a widening
>     primitive conversion.

Specifically, what happens in your case, is a [widening primitive conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html):

> - byte to short, int, long, float, or double

(in your case: from `byte` to `int`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, casting down Monster to vampire , because the object at `ma[0]` is a `Vampire` referenced by Monster.

```
((Vampire)ma[0]).frighten(y);
```