# Why do we cast an object type to a class type in java?

Tags: java, class, object, casting

I'm trying to overwrite the equals method.
Our professor, for some reason, casts the object parameter to the type class (counter).

Could somebody explain to me the logic behind that? If I instead of "Couter that = (Counter) other;" just remove that line and change "that.count" to "other.count", it executes just fine.

```
public class Counter {

    private int count;

    public Counter() {
        count = 2;
    }

    public boolean equals(Counter other) {
        if (other instanceof Counter) {
            Counter that = (Counter) other;
            return (this.count == that.count);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args []) {
        Counter casio = new Counter();
        Counter texas = new Counter();
        System.out.println(casio.equals(texas));
    }
}
```

Comment: I've rolled back the last edit since it invalidates the accepted answer and made the question pointless

Comment: No, the accepted answer corrects my mistake and answers the corrected question.

Comment: maybe there's a misunderstanding about what a Q&A is, because now your `equals` method signature is not wrong

Comment: To avoid confusion, I will choose a different answer that was posted after my correction, if that fits better.

Comment: to avoid confusion don't invalidate answers with your question edits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that the cast is necessary is that the implementor of the `equals` method want to use a field of the class `Counter`, that is, the field `count`.

Because the parameter `other` passed to the method is of type `Object`. The compiler therefore doesn't know that it's actually a `Counter` object. With the typecast you tell the compiler that you're sure that the object is actually a `Counter` instance.

The compiler then allows you to use its defined members, such as `count`.

#### Is typecasting always safe?

Note that the casting *could* normally throw a `ClassCastException` at runtime, but since first the object's type is checked by the `instanceof` operator, it is guaranteed that the object is actually a `Counter` instance, hence it's safe to do this.

#### Why is explicit casting necessary?

Why is explicit typecasting necessary when we are already checking the type with `instanceof`? The reason why this explicit cast is necessary, is because `instanceof` is a *runtime check*. Casting is a compile-time assertion.

---

#### But why not just `boolean equals(Counter other)`?

That's because then you are overloading Object's equals method, instead of overriding.

- [See this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374399/what-is-the-difference-between-method-overloading-and-overriding)

Comment: But doesn't the "instanceof" already verify this check and makes sure that the object is actually a counter object?

Comment: @user472288 Yes, that's why it is safe to cast (see edit).

Comment: Argh.. but if we verify that this is a counter object, why can't we access the count field without casting the object parameter first? Sorry, I'm just confused about this.

Answer (score 3):

The signature of your equals method is wrong. In order to override that method, it needs to have a parameter of type `Object`:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
```

And this requires you to cast `other` to `Counter` and do an `instanceof` check, otherwise you cannot access the `count` field.

Comment: Whoops just a small mistake, question stands (editing now, thanks!).

Comment: This answers the question.  If `other` has type `Object` then your `equals` method won't compile without the type cast.

Comment: But stephen, it does compile, whether I cast it or not. I don't really get how this requires me to cast other to Counter, any specific reason, why can't I access the count field? In addition, why would I only have to do that to the input parameter and not the object that the equals method is executed on.

Comment: This does not compile if you don't cast. If `other` is an `Object`, it has no `count` field which you need for your comparison.

Comment: This runs:  public boolean equals(Counter other) {
  if(other instanceof Counter) {
   return (this.count == other.count);
  }
  else {
   return false;
  }
 }

Comment: But this doesn't: `public boolean equals(Object other) { if(other instanceof Counter) { return (this.count == other.count); } else { return false; } }`.

Comment: @user472288 Yes, because then the method argument is already of type Counter. But then it doesn't fulfill the contract of Object.equals.

Comment: Exactly.  What you probably are missing is that (unlike you) your professor has probably defined `equals` with the correct signature.  But your version has the wrong signature, therefore does not override `Object::equals` ... and therefore won't be used by numerous utility classes, etc that use the standard `equals` method.

Comment: I see, so unless I cast whatever input parameter to the class type, equals will not be overwritten but is essentially a different method that I just implemented, which happens to work in my case?

Comment: Yes.  It happens to work in your case.  But if you put a `Counter` into a `List` and then called `contains` on the list, you would not find it.

Comment: @user472288 exactly. your `casio.equals(texas)` calls your "different" method, which is not overriding anything. You can place the `@Override` annotation above the method to tell the compiler "i want this method to override the superclass's method".

Answer (score 0):

There is no logic... except the fact that there is probably a mistake in the equals methods signature. Here equals is a overloading of the equals methods inherited form the Object class.

the **right** way to define an equals method is to override the equals method inherited form object.

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {
      if(other instanceof Counter) {
        Counter that = (Counter) other;
        return (this.count == that.count);
      }
      else {
          return false;
      }
}
```

in this case the cast is mandatory